# Trigger SSIS package when a file is uploaded to Azure blob storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I want to detect and trigger a SSIS package deployed on the Azure data factory when a file is uploaded to Azure Blob storage. I know it's possible to trigger an SSIS package when a file is dropped to any folder but is it possible to trigger the SSIS package the same way when a file is uploaded to the Azure blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using event triggers .

Data Factory is integrated with Azure Event Grid, which lets you trigger pipelines on an event.
An event-based trigger runs pipelines in response to an event, such as the arrival of a file, or the deletion of a file, in Azure Blob Storage.

[how-to-create-event-trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger)